# HitTest не ищет до конца

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте. Уже пару дней вожусь с HitTest`oм. 
Суть вопроса:

есть такое визуальное дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему, когда мышь находится между двумя текстблоками (FontName и Symbols), результат HitTest`a это ComboBoxBorder, а не стэкпанель?

HitTestParameters - точка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается HitTest производит поиск по контролам, которые хоть как-то отрисовались. Например **Background неравный Transparent** или **BorderThickness = 1 и BorderBrush неравный Transparent**. Даже если контрол будет без границ, но с фоном под цвет нижнего слоя, т.е. не видим для глаза, то WPF его отрисует и HitTest будет его находить.